# DUKPT String Encoding in c#

Tags: c#, encoding

I am having an odd issue when retrieving a decrypted string from DUKPT in .NET, the string comes back in the following format, I have tried turning it into UTF8 but it does not work. Any suggestion would be great

\u0013/9v,╬k┌èQÉα\"û'¢≈åníÇ£åÖΣqV²¢öT\0\u0011╝Dm'═≈;|? 
 U.º\u001c▄Dèk}\u0014┌òÉ\u000fQ=µX\r\u00136τ½]\u0014¥Fù\n╠┼\u001b\u0001╖\nπ╝7╘┐╜B\n ⌐τ%+═S\u0001oE₧Z▄&¢S╥┌├╞=ae\u001a∩\u0004°└\tS0╫▀┘∩\u0019Ö0█CùΓƒ╓┬∞\u0018├╔}-╕\u001aïDφ%»║╡q@┤╡½ \u0019uΩl¡eRÄàD\u0012└√E]VÿêÜ¼▒bΩ¥¿╔╫╬Y\n░lüKg-╥¼°¢aT\u0005>ß\u0019┘⌡.▐»(┤\u007fûA\u0011\t>┐╔(▀l\u0002┘4¥ÿ╘;╟╠σ<░\bΣÅbƒôdÖ¥«╪▓\b╕,EΦ\u001f\t\u00197

Comment: Can you explain how you obtain this data. Converting from UTF8 to a native string is trivial with Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Answer (score 0):

The string is UTF8 and encoded for HTML.  So I saved the string to a file in notepad and selected UTF8.  Then used code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);
            string output = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how would i convert it in app without exporting to a file? Is it possible?

Comment: also what was your output?

Comment: I need to parse that string unfortunately exporting it would not help, Hmm, I tried converting the string to UTF-8 and than doing  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input) but that does not appear to work either

Comment: Yeah that didn't do anything